# Different overfitting for three models with the same structure

Tags: python, machine-learning, deep-learning, tf.keras

I want to design three models that they have the same structure but at the end one of them should have some serious overfitting and another model has less overfitting and the last model has no overfitting.

The idea is that i want to see how much information exist in last layer of each model for some test data. let's say  I m using mnist dataset as training and testing set and the structure of all  models should be like this.

```
# Network architecture
network = Sequential()

# input layer
network.add(Dense(512, activation='relu', input_shape=(28*28,) ))

# Hidden layers
network.add(Dense(64, activation='relu', name='features'))

# Output layer
network.add((Dense(10,activation='softmax')))

network.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='categorical_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])

#train the model
history = network.fit(train_img, train_label, epochs=50, batch_size=256, validation_split=0.2)
```

So now the question is how to change this train model that fulfills my needs for three models with different overfitting.

I m new in machine learning topics and i hope i have explain my question as good as possible.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Overfit:**

The MNIST dataset is rather simple, therefore it should be easy to overfit with the model you are suggesting. Increase the number of epochs: eventually, your model will memorize the training data very well. If you struggle to overfit the data, you might need a more complex network - but I doubt that this will be the case.

**Just right:**

Probably the easiest wat to obtain the model which is just right (no overfit or underfit) use a callback. Specifically, we can use [early stopping](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/callbacks/EarlyStopping). The callback will stop training if the validation loss stops improving. For your code, all you have to do is modify the training as follows:

1. First define a callback

   ```
   callback_es = tf.keras.callbacks.EarlyStopping(monitor = 'val_loss')
   ```
2. Add the callback to your training

   ```
   history = network.fit(train_img, train_label, epochs=50, batch_size=256, validation_split=0.2, callback = [callback_es])
   ```

**Underfit**

Similar idea as with overfitting. In this case, you want to stop your training early on. Train your model for a limited number of epochs only. If you find that your model overfits to quickly, try to lower the learning rate.